# Is it ever safe to set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to FALSE? Even if you control both servers?

Tags: php, security, ssl, curl

I have an internal API where an app running on a shared host fetches semi-sensitive data from a dedicated server via HTTPS. I have a certificate on the dedicated server, and the app on the shared host makes an API call via https.

The certificate works fine if you test the SSL connection on a web browser, but CURL in PHP is giving me some trouble. I've set my `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false` to clear the problem for testing.

Is it safe to leave this set to false, because I control the traffic on both ends? In fact, do I even need an SSL cert? As long as it goes over HTTPS it's secure, right?

Am I in danger of a man-in-the-middle attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to leave this set to false, because I control the traffic on both ends? In fact, do I even need an SSL cert? As long as it goes over HTTPS it's secure, right?

No. You are only safe if you not only control both ends but also everything in between. If you have a single cable between two computers and control both computers than you are probably safe. If there is any cabling, router etc which might be accessed by somebody else you are not safe anymore.

> Am I in danger of a man-in-the-middle attack?

Yes, unless you can control everything in between you cannot prevent a man in the middle. And unless you validate the certificates you can neither detect nor prevent the attack.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I will get working on making sure PHP CURL can validate these certs.

Comment: what if i use SSL ONLY on server, not client on shared hosting? is it secure enough?

Comment: @MohammadSalehi: this is a different question and should not be asked in a comment. But in short: it is not secure enough since a man in the middle attack is still possible.